# java text file new line

Tags: java, string, parsing, line

I am trying to capture information and then parse it to a txt file.

I have tried using `\n` to create a new line, but the program seems to append the string on the same line.

```
try {

    FileWriter mother = new FileWriter(file, true);
    mother.write(newsHeadline.attr("title") + '\n');
    mother.close();
} catch(IOException e) {    
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using System.lineSeparator() maybe help you

```
mother.write(newsHeadline.attr("title") + System.lineSeparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 7/8:

```
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true), true)) {
    out.println(newsHeadline.attr("title"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `official` way to get the line separator is the following:

```
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

So I would use:

```
myPrintWriter.print("Something." + newline);
```

The advantage of using the system property, is that it will word regardless of the platform it is being run on, as the property will change depending on the platform. (Windows / Unix)